# I have a bug with my page that stops it from displaying in the correct position

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I have built a program that is just a simple page system, a few features like dynamically adding buttons for new pages, a scrollbar for content, etc. But, I am getting an odd issue with my Home page. Here is a gif with the problem:

https://gyazo.com/cb42cbab30fa7754127854589e7a288f

Once I pack_forget() the home page, and then pack() it again, it appears lower on screen. I thought this may have been an item on the home page, causing it to be lowered but it isn't, I have removed all content from the page and the issue persists, and the other pages do not seem to be affected. The issue persists if the other pages are removed from the program entirely, so they are not pushing it down in any way.

I do not have any other frames apart from the pages that get inherited by the Page class, and if i remove all of them plus the content for the home page, the issue still persists. I am really baffled by what this issue is as every page uses the same code and yet the issue is present for the home page and not the others.

MainView

```
    # import gi
# gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
# from gi.repository import Gtk

""" tkinter imports """
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import font

""" Page imports """
from Home import Home


#maybe these should go in the MainView class
""" Constants """
TITLE = "Program"
ABOUT_MESSAGE = "About"

debug = "debug_mode"
debug_mode = True

class MainView(tk.Frame):

    """ MainView attributes """
    my_font = None

    LANGUAGES = []
    # LANGUAGES = [Java, Python, HTML, Java, Python, HTML, Java, Python, HTML]
    pages = {}


    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        #tooth_fairy_protocol()
        my_font = font.Font(family = "Helvetica", size = 30, weight = "bold")

        #

        # create pages
        if debug_mode == True:
            page = Home(self, highlightbackground="pink", highlightcolor="pink", highlightthickness=10)
        else:
            page = Home(self)  

        self.pages[page.__class__.__name__] = page 
        self.show_home()

        self.setup_menu(parent, self.pages)


    def show_home(self):
        home_page = self.pages["Home"]
        home_page.pack_forget()
        for item in home_page.pages:
            home_page.pages[item].pack_forget()
        home_page.show() 

    def setup_menu(self, parent, pages):
        """ Setup menu bar """
        # setup the bar for the menu
        menubar = tk.Menu(self)

        # setup the button for the menu
        menubutton = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)

        # setup file menu
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
        filemenu.add_command(label = "Home", command = lambda: self.show_home())
        filemenu.add_command(label = "Sandbox", command = lambda: messagebox.showinfo("Title", "Feature not implemented yet"))
        filemenu.add_command(label = "About", command = lambda: messagebox.showinfo("Title", ABOUT_MESSAGE))


        # add menu button to the menu bar
        menubar.add_cascade(label = "Menu", menu = menubutton)

        # add options to menu button
        menubutton.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = filemenu)
        menubutton.add_command(label = "Exit", command = self.quit)

        parent.config(menu = menubar)

def center(win):
    """ Centers the window on the screen. """
    win.update_idletasks()
    width = win.winfo_width()
    height = win.winfo_height()
    x = (win.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - (width // 2)
    y = (win.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - (height // 2)
    win.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(width, height, x, y))

def tooth_fairy_protocol():
    """
    Pillow Check
    install pillow on a windows pc
    """
    try:
        import PIP
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        print("Installing PIP")

        import subprocess
        r = subprocess.run(["pip", "install", "Pillow"])
        # r = subprocess.run(["pip", "install", "gobject", "PyGObject"])

        if r.returncode != 0:
            print("PIL could not be installed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()

    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    # main.grid(rowspan = 2, row = 1)

    # change aspect ratio of the program
    # root.wm_geometry("1280x720")
    sizex = 1280
    sizey = 720
    posx  = 100
    posy  = 100
    root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))
    # center the program on screen
    center(root)

    # changes the window icon
    tk.Tk.iconbitmap(root, default = "icon.ico")

    # changes the title of the program
    tk.Tk.wm_title(root, TITLE)
    root.mainloop()
```

Page

```
    """ tkinter imports """
import tkinter as tk

class Page(tk.Frame):
    parent = {}
    pages = {}
    canvas= None
    buttonframe = None
    debug = False

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.debug = True
        for item in args:
                if item == "debug_mode":
                    self.debug = True


        # Add page title
        label = tk.Label(self, text=self.__class__.__name__).pack(side = tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

        # create a canvas object and a vertical scrollbar for scrolling it
        vscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient = tk.VERTICAL)
        vscrollbar.pack(fill = tk.Y, side = tk.RIGHT, expand = False)
        canvas= self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bd = 0, highlightbackground="yellow", highlightcolor="yellow", highlightthickness=10, yscrollcommand = vscrollbar.set)
        canvas.pack(side = tk.LEFT, fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)
        vscrollbar.config(command = canvas.yview)

         # reset the view
        canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        # create a frame inside the canvas which will be scrolled with it
        if self.debug:
            self.buttonframe = tk.Frame(canvas, highlightbackground="red", highlightcolor="red", highlightthickness=10)
        else:
            self.buttonframe = tk.Frame(canvas)
        interior_id = canvas.create_window(0, 0, window = self.buttonframe, anchor = tk.NW)

        def _configure_interior(event):
            # update the scrollbars to match the size of the inner frame
            size = (self.buttonframe.winfo_reqwidth(), self.buttonframe.winfo_reqheight())
            canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 %s %s" % size)
            if self.buttonframe.winfo_reqwidth() != canvas.winfo_width():
                # update the canvas's width to fit the inner frame
                canvas.config(width = self.buttonframe.winfo_reqwidth())
        self.buttonframe.bind('<Configure>', _configure_interior)

        def _configure_canvas(event):
            if self.buttonframe.winfo_reqwidth() != canvas.winfo_width():
                # update the inner frame's width to fill the canvas
                canvas.itemconfigure(interior_id, width = canvas.winfo_width())
        canvas.bind('<Configure>', _configure_canvas)

    def show(self):
        """ 
        Show the Page 
        """

        self.pack(side = "top", expand = True, fill = tk.BOTH)
```

Home

```
    """ tkinter imports """
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk



""" Page imports """
from Page import Page


class Home(Page):
    """ 
    Home page of the program - this will have all language options on, each will link to their own page 
    """

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

    def show_page(self, language, pages):
        self.pack_forget()
        pages[language.__name__].show()
```

If anyone can help me with this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That means to remove any code unnecessary to create the problem and also to include all relevant imports.

Comment: ive minimized the code so it can be copy and pasted now

Answer (score 0):

This was difficult. I'm not familiar with your chosen solution and I don't really understand how it's supposed to work. It's difficult to find the problem in an action that spans several classes.

Just to give an example of what may constitute a minimal example I have included some code which replicates the behaviour. To activate just press <kbd>Space</kbd> instead of using menus.

```
import tkinter as tk
from Home import Home

class MainView(tk.Frame):
    pages = {}

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        page = Home(self, highlightbackground="pink",
                        highlightcolor="pink", highlightthickness=10)

        self.pages[page.__class__.__name__] = page 
        self.show_home()
        parent.bind('<space>', lambda event: self.show_home())

    def show_home(self):
        home_page = self.pages["Home"]
        home_page.pack_forget()

        for item in self.pages:
            self.pages[item].pack_forget()
        home_page.show() 

root = tk.Tk()
main = MainView(root)
main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.wm_geometry("500x500+500+200")
root.mainloop()
```

Perhaps someone else can use this code to try and solve this problem. I have not done anything to the other classes though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [figbeam's much more minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55458322/3714930) I was able to find the problem.

In your `Page` class, you initialize the frame as

```
tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

The thing to notice here is that you *don't* pass the `parent`. Therefore, the `Page` frame will not have the `MainView` as it's parent, but the root window. Because of this, these two frames are packed on top of each other, the `Page` above the `MainView`. When you `pack_forget` the `Page`, and re`pack` it, it is now placed *under* the `MainView` frame.

The solution would be to give the frame initialization in the `Page` class the `parent` like

```
tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hadn't realised i missed that. But, because it took a while for someone to respond, i did end up modifying the code using grid instead of place, which solved my issue. But, i ended up encountering another issue just now, which this has just solved, thanks! :D